# htaccess limit the url access to subdomains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel

So basically I have the following public_html structure:

```
/main
/subdomains
```

So far I have managed to make it so one cannot access /subdomains directly by setting:

**www.site.com/subdomains**

However lets say I have a subdomain called projects:

**projects.site.com**

In a folder:

*/subdomains/projects/*

Now if one knows the url one can access the projects folder via:

**site.com/subdomains/projects.**

What I want to do is prevent this behaviour so the only way to access the subdomain is via the proper subdomain url: **projects.site.com.**

If this can be done via *Cpanel* then great but I am not shy about using *.htaccess* to do it.  Just bear in mind when writing your answer that I am not excatly fluent yet so detailed answers please.

Answer (score 1):

Place this rule in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}:%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^.]+)\.[^:]+:/subdomains/\1/
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

- `RewriteCond` here is actng on combination of 2 variables `%{HTTP_HOST}` and `%{REQUEST_URI}`.
- `:` is used as separator between 2 variables.
- `([^.]+)` is capturing subdomain name in group #1 (e.g. projects)
- `/subdomains/\1/` matches REQUEST_URI with back reference #1
- If condition is true then forbidden error is returned.

Answer (score 0):

As a fast answer you can rename the folder where you stored your webfiles. Your example is projects:

Lets assume your files are stored in /var/www/projects.files

Just create a VHost with a servername projects.yourdomain.com

In reverse it is not possible to call the site by using yourdomain.com/projects